# Loki Distributed with S3 backend not pulling data to Grafana dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, grafana-loki

Loki Distributed with S3 backend not pulling data to Grafana dashboard, data is pushing to the S3 bucket but not shown in the dashboard.

While checking the pod logs we can see the following error,

level=warn ts=2022-12-07T21:56:10.957376174Z caller=client.go:369 component=client host=loki-stack:3100 msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=-1 error="Post "http://loki-stack:3100/loki/api/v1/push": dial tcp 172.20.215.236:3100: connect: connection refused"

Please helps to fix this issue.

Thanks.